# Finding whether there are two coprime numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to find an algorithm that for a given array A = [a1, a2, ..., a_n] of integers returns true if there are two indexes i !== j such that gcd(ai, aj) = 1 (and false otherwise). I'm trying to minimalize the complexity of this algorithm.

Of course, the obvious solution would be to use Euclid's algorithm for each pair (ai, aj), but its pesimistic complexity is n(n+1)/2 times the complexity of Euclid's algorithm.

Is there a way to do that in O(n) or O(n*log(n))?

Comment: How large can the `a[1], ..., a[n]` numbers be?

Comment: Well, I'm proggraming on a paper sheet, but let's suppose they're reasonably small, let's say 0 < ai < 32 767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let hasCoprimePair(S) be procedure that returns True if there is a pair of coprimes S and otherwise False, and let it have a two argument variant hasCoprimePair(S, T) that returns True if there exists a pair coprimes, one integer in S and one in T, and otherwise False.

Now let p be a prime number. Take a set S (of integers) and divide it into two sets, T and U, so that T contains those elements of S that are divisible by p and U contains the other elements (those not divisible by p). Because every element in T is divisible by p, it follows that hasCoprimePair(T) = False necessarily. So we have

```
hasCoprimePair(S) = hasCoprimePair(T, U) or hasCoprimePair(U)
```

The first subproblem (hasCoprimePair(T, U)) can be solved in |T|x|U| GCD-operations and the second subproblem is recursive; you can again split it using a different value of p this time. Splitting S into T and U sets requires O(n) time, so you save some GCD-operations compared to the naive algorithm but the asymptotic complexity is still quadratic.

Comment: One (non-asymptote-improving) optimisation: try primes in increasing order, and give the single-set version of `hasCoprimePair(S)` a second parameter k, recording the highest prime that has been proven to be absent from S.  Then every element in S is either a prime, or a product of 2 or more primes that each must be > k.  So, if (k+1)*(k+1) > max(S), we can conclude that *all* elements in S are primes; so if in addition |S| >= 2 we can immediately return "true" (since any 2 primes are coprime to each other).

Answer (score 0):

For existence of atleast two number that are coprime
the GCD of whole array must be 1.

Comment: If two number in the list are coprime, then the `gcd` of the whole array must be `1`. However, the converse may not be true. Take for instance three primes, `p`, `q` and `r` and form the array `pq, pr, qr`. No two elements are coprime, but the whole array is.

Comment: Yeah converse is not true